# NestJS GET return file from HTTP response

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs

I need to return file what i getting from HTTP response from another server.
Schema: MY-FRONTEND <-> MY-BACKEND <-> BACKEND-WITH-FILES
I have a controller

```
export class MyController {
  constructor(
    private fileService: FileService,
  ) { }

  @Get('download')
  download(@Res() res, @Query('id') id: string) {
    this.fileService.download(id)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
         // how i can send file from there to my front-end?   
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Also FileService is:

```
@Injectable()
export class FileService {
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) { }

  download(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.get('OTHER_SERVICE_URL + SOME_FILE_ID', {
      headers: {
        'API-KEY': 'SOME API KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).pipe(
      map((response: any) => response.data),
    );
  }
}
```

File service return pptx file in body with Content-Disposition header, content something like that:
[image]

What the correct way to return correct file to my front-end? Because i got broken file if i try to get it from my back-end, but if i ask the file from the CDN (FileService) i've got correct file.

The all headers from postman when i try to get file directly is
[image]

In my case i need to get file on front-end and download it.

Comment: In case if you have to download a file in postman, Instead of clicking the `Send button` on Postman, use the `Send and Download` button and see if it download the correct file.
Try setting appropriate content type in the response (`res`) before sending it to frontend

Comment: @Amolpskamble no, file is incorrect if i send it across my back-end, seems like body is the same but size bigger for the 1MB. If i do request dirrectly to third party back-end its correct. Content type didn't help, file bigger and dont opening